# Transformers, input voltage range

Tags: transformer

I have a transformer based AC fan controller (rated for 230V input) with five output steps ( 230V(5) - 200V(4) - 160V(3) - 140V(2) - 125V(1) ). I would like to have more fine grained steps, and am thus thinking to connect two equal transformers in series, giving me a total of 25 different steps.

The second transformer would then get as input the output from the first transfomer (125V-230V). Is it likely that this would work (assuming there are no other components inside the controller which requires 240V)? In other words, does a transformer work well with any voltage below the rated voltage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd have thought a variac might be a better solution, but yes, you can feed the output of one transformer into the input of another, and driving below its rated voltage is not going to be a problem.

You're not really connecting them 'in series', but I know what you mean.

Comment: Although I may follow the advice from @gwideman, I'm accepting your answer since it clearly states that a transformer may well be driven below rated voltage.

Answer (score 0):

In principle it will operate, but transformers have losses, so it will suffer two of those losses. Additionally, you should calculate exactly what ratios this actually produces, because a number of the combinations will be the same as or similar to other combinations... so it won't necessarily be particularly fine-grained.

A better solution would be an AC motor speed controller. And I see in another question you are asking about microcontroller control of this speed. In which case you can probably find an AC motor speed controller with a control interface.

Comment: Not quite what I hoped to find, but there are a bunch of these on eBay for a few bucks: "AC motor speed control". Speed controlled from a knob, which you could easily drive with a servo. It would be better to have an electronic speed control input, but whatever route you go there needs to be reliable electrical isolation between the 220V circuit and your microcontroller.

Comment: But I should also note that different kinds of AC motor require different kinds of controller (and accommodation for starting). So you do have to figure out what kind of motor you're dealing with, and what kind of controller is needed for that type.

Comment: Good points, thanks! Looks like my solution will give 15 unique steps (68, 76, 85, 87, 97, 109, 111, 122, 125, 139, 140, 160, 174, 200, 230). These steps will actually cover my needs, but I will look into the option of buying a completely new controller as well.