# Does a transformer work well below its rated input voltage?

Tags: transformer

I found myself [answering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/305961/detect-one-out-of-five-distinct-voltage-levels/305989#305989) a recent question that I now have doubts over. For a given transformer, is the output voltage proportional to the input voltage for all input voltages? So specifically if VRi is the rated input voltage, and VRo the  rated output, does *x* VRi = *x* VRo for 0 < *x* < 1? For example, will you get 0.6V out from a 240V /6V transformer if you input 24V only? Since transformers are complicated little things, I wonder if there might be non linearity especially with a small *x* .

I've found [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/105778/transformers-input-voltage-range) and [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/144770/using-a-transformer-with-400-volt-rated-primary-side-with-a-120-volt-line) question that initially seemed to ask what I wanted to know, but the actual answers drifted onto other matters.

Comment: Nonlinearity in transformers is mostly related to magnetic hysteresis and magnetic saturation, both of which become less significant with lower currents. So I would expect it to work fine.

Comment: Bit of a yes and no thing, depending on how accurate you define the equals sign and the range for x. Too tired to explain properly, so I'll leave that to someone else. When "aberration" occurs depends on shape and size and/or primary inductance. Edit: Your answer will very likely work near enough to linear. 90V is quite high still.

Comment: @Asmyldof thanks, I was worried I'd suggested a duff solution. But this begs the obvious question - how low can you go?

Comment: That depends on the specific transformer parameters, but for most I'd not be surprised if 5% of rated still works close enough to expected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the power transformer at a lower voltage with no problems. But you cannot violate the original current limits of either winding nor should you deviate substantially from the design frequency.